# Adding SDKTools project causing duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, skmaps

I am adding the SDKTools as source code and it's third party library Reachability and AFNetworking is causing duplicate symbols with my included library by cocoa pod. I have tried to adding SDK Tools from cocoapod but doesn't works as i am adding use_framework! causes error in some library which dont had framework support. Tried adding "other c flag" to build setting. Please help me the way out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding via Cocoapods then the Reachability and AFNetworking dependencies are included by default (hopefully in a future update we'll link them as external libraries).

Grab the SDKTools from [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) (the downloadable project) and you'll be able to remove all external libraries - in the downloadable project you have full access to the code making up the SDKTools project.

Comment: removing external libraries cause missing classes error as libSDKTool.a is including *.o of these classes.

Comment: Don't include the compiled version of the SDKTools project - modify the project or include the classes themselves

Comment: Please can you please explain further i am adding the project into my own project then adding it into target dependency and adding it libSDKTool.a to "Link Binary with libraries" Thanks